# Deriving law of motion for Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a continuum of objects, all affected by Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I want to find the mass of those that are moving upwards, which I will make more precise in the discrete-time approximation that follows.

---

Discretize a grid over `a` with step size $\Delta_a = \bar a - \underline a$. Time period is $\Delta_t = (\Delta a/\sigma)^2$. In the interior, $a$ increases with probability $1/2 (1 + \mu \Delta_a/\sigma^2)$, and decreases with probability $1/2 (1 - \mu \Delta_a/\sigma^2)$. This yields an expected value of $\mu \Delta_t$ with second moment $\sigma^2 \Delta_t$.

---

Now, what I am interested in, in discrete time, is separating the "upward-movers" from the "downward-movers", and compute the "speed" ($\Delta_a/\Delta_t$) for each of these.

For upward-movers, we have `how much you move upwards X prob of moving upwards` per unit of time:

$$\Delta_a \cdot \left[\frac{1}{2}(1 + \frac{\mu\Delta_a}{\sigma^2}) \right]/\Delta_t\\
= \frac{1}{2}\left[\sigma^2\frac{\Delta_t}{\Delta_a}  + \frac{\mu\Delta_a^2}{\sigma^2})\right]/\Delta_t\\
= \frac{1}{2}\left[\sigma^2\frac{\Delta_t}{\Delta_a} + \mu\Delta_t\right]/\Delta_t\\
= \frac{1}{2}\left[ \sigma^2\frac{1}{\Delta_a} + \mu\right]  $$

Now, when $\Delta_t \to 0$, we have $\Delta_a \to 0$, so the first term explodes. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using dimensional analysis to check your derivation?  What are the dimensions of $\sigma$, $\Delta_{a}$, $\mu$, etc.?

Comment: The term $\sigma^2 \Delta t/ \Delta_a$ in the second line: where does it come from?

Comment: @caverac It's $1 \cdot \Delta_a$, where I then rewrote the definition of $\Delta_t$ to obtain $\Delta_a = \sigma^2 \Delta_t/\Delta_a$.